# How to persiste Three entities all at once using spring data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

hi guys i want to persiste three objects all at once heres the code :

```
@Entity
public class Mission implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private Long               id;

@OneToMany( mappedBy = "mission" )
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Station>      stations         = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany( mappedBy = "mission" )

@JsonManagedReference
private List<StationPrice> stationsPrice    = new ArrayList<>();
}
Station :
@Entity
 public class Station implements Serializable {



@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private Long              id;
private String            station;

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@JsonBackReference
private Mission           mission;
}
```

StationPrice :

```
@Entity
public class StationPrice implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */


@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private Long              Id;
private String            stationsName;
private String            stationsPrice;

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@JsonBackReference
private Mission           mission;
}
```

so when i persiste his i used the folowing methode :

```
@Override
public Mission addMision( Mission mission ) {

    List<Station> stations = mission.getStations();
    List<StationPrice> stationPrices = mission.getStationsPrice();

    mission.setStations( new ArrayList<Station>() );
    for ( Station station : stations ) {
        station.setMission( mission );
        mission.getStations().add( station );
        mission = stationRepository.save( station ).getMission();
    }
    return mission;

}
```

this Methode persiste only the mission entity and station entity but not stationPrice entity, is there a way to persiste the three entities all at once?

Answer (score 0):

I think if Add

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=Station.class,  cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Station> stations = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  targetEntity=StationPrice.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@JsonManagedReference
private List<StationPrice> stationsPrice = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And then you can simply persist Mission Entity, which will persist both station and station price.

**Edit**
By the way, your ERM looks strange to me, and in the code, you loop stations of mission, then add then back into mission? and stationPrice is not used at all?